# Extract icon from executable that's in memory

Tags: .net, dll, icons, executable

Does anyone know an API function to extract an icon resource from an executable file that's in RAM (inside, say, a MemoryStream)?

All of the icon-extracting functions I've seen so far depend on the executable file being present on disk.  I'd like to extract the icon without having to write the exe to a temp file, and then loading the resources from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is never a real problem.  Windows has the hard requirement that an executable is a file on disk.  You can't start a process otherwise.  Since you have to write the file to disk anyway, you never have a problem extracting resources from it with an API that requires a path to a file.

Comment: Thanks; I'll have to bite the bullet on that one.

Comment: "This is never a real problem" -- Sadly, you don't get to define what problems are "real." For instance, I want to pull the icons from a network capture without touching the disk.

Answer (score 0):

if we are talking about taking icon from already build DLL use Reflector

```
http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/
```

to open the DLL and the just click on the icon with the right mouse button and click Save As
also this can be done by code using reflection

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.Load("SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3");
Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream( "MyNamespace.SubFolder.MyImage.bmp" );
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap( myStream );
```

Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: I think he specific said that he want to read icons from memory.